# NavLink interactions with boostrap classes

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble setting up my routing using 'react-router-dom'. The problem is if I use the NavLink class, the a tag is lost and bootstrap wont display the css behavior.

What i'd like to happen is figure out a way to get the classes working like a normal a tag. Even if I have the btn btn-outline-primary, having the NavLink will interfere with the css properties.

***edit: I found the problem. If I set all routes for testing purpose to="/", every link is going to be active. So, afterall, Bootstrap is working perfectly, just have to make sure to test it once all routes are set.

```
<li className="nav-item">
  <NavLink to='/' className="btn btn-light mr-1" href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Perfíl
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try nesting the li in the Navlinks and also pass the bootstrap classes to the li and not the Navlink route. remove the href

Comment: @GabrielMartinez have you set your routes in app.js? you need to set you routes first and assign the home "/" route the home component for the navlink to work..

Comment: Yes, the problem is displaying the classes, not the routes. 
<NavLink to='/'>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link">Finalizar sesión</a>
                    </li>
                </NavLink>
won't display correctly

Comment: Let me clarify, when i try to use NavLink as en "a" tag, bootstrap nav class messes up. The nav-item works, but the nav-link className on a <NavLink> does not work at all.. the only way is using an 'a' tag, but then i will messing up the route